# Behaviour of \n(new line ) character geting from database

Tags: java, database, string, oracle

I am facing some weird issue.I am fetching a email template from database "Hi \n How are you? \n story continues". I am assigning this to string in my java application and sending email. The final output should be

```
Hi
How are you?
story continues
```

But my result is like this

```
Hi \n How are you? \n story continue
```

Instead of getting from db, if I hard code in the string I am getting in right way.

What might be causing \n to be ineffective?

Is there a way can I make \n effective in java layer?

Comment: How is the `\n` getting there? You should use actual newline characters.

Comment: Does your DB have `\n` or `\\n`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    String str = //value read from DB
    str = str.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html). The method that you need is `unescapeJava()`.

It is inside [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).